# URLs not found after deploying create-react-app build to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, create-react-app

I've uploaded a create-react-app build (with an app.yaml file) to a GCP bucket. The app has then been deployed on a App Engine instance using the cloud shell.

Going to the app's root URL works fine. But going to `example.com/anything` returns the following error:

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /anything was not found on this server.

App.yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(html|css|js))
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/(.*\.(html|css|js))

- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

Comment: Use `url: .*` for the second handler.

Comment: Hi @typeofgraphic, can you please share how to deploy create-react-app to Google App Engine step by step? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a handler for `/anything`.  If you want a catch-all url, use regex type handler:

```
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

or, if you want to serve them `anything.html` as a static file, put it in your `build` dir, and navigate to `/anything.html`.  Your first handler is set up to map that url.