# React app giving 404 error when deployed to GCP

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, web-deployment, app.yaml

I have deployed my react app to GCP's App engine. It successfully deploys and the landing page is accessible. However none of the routes work. All the routes are giving '404' error.
I am pretty sure its the app.yaml configuration that has issue. Help please!

#### app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016400/11380693

Comment: I tried that out, did not work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using both `static_files` and `static_dir` to your `/` url.

You need to either use `static_files` or `static_dir`.

From the description of your question it looks like you want to use `static_dir` to match everything that is inside the directory after the `url: /`.

As stated in the documentation:

- [static_dir](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_static_dir): The path to the directory containing the static files, from the application root directory. Everything after the end of the matched url pattern is appended to static_dir to form the full path to the requested file.
- [static_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_static_files): A static file pattern handler associates a URL pattern with paths to static files uploaded with the application. The URL pattern regular expression can define regular expression groupings to be used in the construction of the file path. You can use this instead of static_dir to map to specific files in a directory structure without mapping the entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe in your public url in the .env file.
When yarn / npm is building the project it will use the public url ( If you have configured to use like that).
You can find this using the browser console. It will print the failing file uri's.
In my case I had the failing uri like this.

`mysite.com/localhost/static/main.2342.js`

This means I had localhost appended mistakenly to the URL.